# If PHP session ID is stored in a cookie then why from a browser the session id can't be seen?

Tags: php, cookies

If I look only name,content,domain,path,expires etc are shown from the bowser tool.Is it possible to see the session Id associated with a cookie from a browser?

Comment: If you aren't using GET for PHP Session IDs, all Session IDs are stored in Cookies in the Browser. The default setting is to use Cookies. The Cookie should be visible in your Browser's Cookie Tool with the name "PHP_SESSION_ID" if it wasnt changed in your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Usually PHP_SESSION_ID = cookie name.